# Find the maximum value of $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization

Let $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, where $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers. It is given that $-1 \le P(x) \le 1$ if and only if $-1 \le x \le 1$. Find the maximum value of $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|$.

I believe that the answer should be $7$. I have gotten as far as here:

> Let $\lambda = 1$. Sub in $\lambda, \frac{\lambda}{2}, -\frac{\lambda}{2}$ in $P(x)$. We get that
> $$|\lambda a+b+\lambda c+d|,|\frac{\lambda}{8} a+\frac{1}{4}b+\frac{\lambda}{2} c+d|,|-\frac{\lambda}{8} a+\frac{1}{4}b-\frac{\lambda}{2} c+d|$$
> are $\le 1$.
> Note that $$|\lambda a+b|=|\frac{4}{3}\times(1)-2\times(2)+\frac{2}{3}\times(3)|\le|\frac{4}{3}\times1-2\times-1+\frac{2}{3}\times1|=4,$$ where $(1),(2),(3)$ are the three expressions above.
> Similarly, $$|\lambda c+d|=|-\frac{1}{3}\times(1)+2\times(2)-\frac{2}{3}\times(3)|\le|-\frac{1}{3}\times-1+2\times1-\frac{2}{3}\times-1|=3.$$
> The polynomial $4x^3-3x$ is an example of $7$ being able to be achieved.

However, I do not have the sufficient knowledge to complete the proof from this point.

Comment: What was your idea when you are doing these estimates? What are things that you still need to show?

Comment: I did it when I thought I could make $|\lambda a+b|$ and $|\lambda c+d|$ with those expressions. I need to show that the sum of the two is the max value of $|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|$.

Comment: I guess my question is also: why did you consider $|\lambda a + b|$ in the first place?

Comment: By intuition. I guess that's just it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1589275/78967

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\max{(1/\alpha+1/\beta+|1/\gamma|+|1/\delta|)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584068/what-is-max1-alpha1-beta1-gamma1-delta)